# how to stash/unstash files in Jenkins shared library function

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to write a "stash_files" and "unstash_files" method in my shared library class.

- does `stash` works only from workspace?
- do I need to copy `file.txt` into workspace first?
- I know that `stash` gets file_name and a stash_name(to be unstashed later) how does it work here in shared lib?

`Jenkinsfile`:

```groovy
@Library('Utils')
import org.jenkins.Utils
utils = new Utils(steps)
node() {
stage('first'){
     utils.doit("file.txt")
}}
```

shared library:

```groovy
package src.org.jenkins

class Utils implements Serializable {
def steps

Utils(steps) {
    this.steps = steps
}

def doit(filename){
  this.steps.sh "echo hii > /tmp/$filename"
  this.stash_file(filename)
}

def stash_files(filename){
  this.steps.stash filename
}
def unstash_files(filename){
  this.steps.unstash filename
```

Comment: What is your use case for this and what are you trying to accomplish?  Have you looked at the [`stash` step reference documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build)?

Comment: @mkobit yes I did. I'd like to do lots of operations on this file before stashing it. therefore, function in shared library is great. 
my use case is to move this file between stages which are not on the same node.

Comment: Got it. So, `stash`/`unstash` will work across nodes/workspaces - _"Stashed files are not otherwise available and are generally discarded at the end of the build."_. You will need a workspace to `stash` because that is where the files come from. Same idea with `unstash`. There are probably other questions regarding how to use `stash`/`unstash`.

Comment: thanks for the information! though I did not find any example on how to use it in shared library which is my main issue. Regular stash/unstash from a jenkinsfile works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```groovy
def stash_file(file_name, name){
    this.steps.stash ('includes': file_name, 'name': name)
}

def unstash_file(name){
    this.steps.unstash name
}
```